# Sharing information with browser tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, local-storage

Think I have a page with only one input

Now, I open three tabs of this page in browser.

I need a code so If I change the element in one tab, two other input changes automatically.
So if I type 'hello' in tab one, tab two and tab three input text will be 'hello'

Is there any javascript\backbone\angular code that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use cookies to relay this data to the other pages - of course this would be dependent on your user accepting them:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as a chat program.

1. user A enters message
2. server receives the message and broadcasts to all participating users(A,B,C)
3. user B,C receives the message
4. user B,C append the message to their chat window

By doing this way all user A,B,C shares the same messages.

From the above case, replace #4 to "replace the text by the message received"

With HTML5, there is WebSocket to make this totally possible.

Here is an example how to make chat program using websocket(I googled it)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-node-js-and-websockets-to-build-a-chat-service/